# Access a method within another method of the same class. Creating a Dynamic Array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, linked-list

first of all, I realise that there is already a class for a dynamic array in C++. I am doing this out of experimentation, not neccecity. I have a class called DynamicCharArray. My intention is to implement a dynamic array by using a linked list. It contains several methods, some private and some public. Two of these are:

```
void InterInsert(node *&head, node *&last, int index, char input)
```

and

```
void insert(int index, char input).
```

InterInsert(...) contains all the code to actually insert the character into my array. insert(...) is an abstraction.

My questions are:
Am I on the right track, and if not, how should I implement this?
Why am I getting the following errors?:

error: expected primary-expression before '*' token
     this -> InterInsert(node *&head, node *&last, int index, char input);

error: 'head' was not declared in this scope
     this -> InterInsert(node *&head, node *&last, int index, char input);

error: expected primary-expression before '*' token
     this -> InterInsert(node *&head, node *&last, int index, char input);

error: 'last' was not declared in this scope
     this -> InterInsert(node *&head, node *&last, int index, char input);
error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
     this -> InterInsert(node *&head, node *&last, int index, char input);

error: expected primary-expression before 'char'
     this -> InterInsert(node *&head, node *&last, int index, char input);

This program is still in it's early stages. But I would dearly like to fix these errors before continuing. Many methods may be added in the future, suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated.

in DynamicCharArray.h:

```
#ifndef DYNAMICCHARARRAY_H
#define DYNAMICCHARARRAY_H

class DynamicCharArray
{

private:
struct node
{
    char let;
    node *next;
    int index;
};

int size;

bool isEmpty(node *head);
void InterInsert(node *&head, node *&last, int index, char input);
void insertAsFirstElement(node *&head, node *&last, char input);

public:
DynamicCharArray(); //create empty array

void insert(int index, char input);    //insert an element into array    
void printAll();    //print all data values contained in the array

char index(int numIn);  //returns the char value in a particular index. Same effect as: myArray[numIn] instead I will call it as: myChar = myDynamicCharArray.index(5)

~DynamicCharArray();

};

#endif // DYNAMICCHARARRAY_H
```

in DynamicCharArray.cpp:

```
#include "dynamicchararray.h"

#define NULL 0

struct node
{
char let;
node *next;
int index;
};

int size;

DynamicCharArray::DynamicCharArray() //create empty array
{
node *head = NULL;
node *last;
node list;

size = 0;
}

bool DynamicCharArray::isEmpty(node *head)
{
if(head == NULL)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
}

void DynamicCharArray::InterInsert(node *&head, node *&last, int index, char input)
{
    if(isEmpty(head))
    {
        insertAsFirstElement(head, last, input);
    }
    else
    {
        node *newNode = new node;   //new node is dynamicly created (space created)
        newNode -> let = input;     //value that is passed is assigned to new node
        newNode -> next = last -> next; //the new node's pointer gets the same value as the last pointer, as it is now in the 'place' where last was.
        last -> next = newNode;     //The new node is now the last, and the last node now points to it
        last = last -> next;        //make last, point to the last element in the list
    }

}

void DynamicCharArray::insertAsFirstElement(node *&head, node *&last, char input)    //insert as first element function from standard linked list program
{
    node *newNode = new node;
    newNode -> index = 0;
    newNode -> let = input;
    newNode -> next = NULL; //Here is the difference between the first element, and the rest. Here the tail/last pointer to node does not have a value yet. It will get this node's value in the rest of this function.
    head = newNode;
    last = newNode;
}

void DynamicCharArray::insert(int index,char input)   //insert an element into array
{
InterInsert(node *&head, node *&last, int index, char input);  //HERE IS THE LINE THE ERRORS ARE REFERING TO
}

char DynamicCharArray::index(int numIn) //returns the char value in a particular index. Same effect as: myArray[numIn] instead I will call it as: myChar = myDynamicCharArray.index(5)
{

}

DynamicCharArray::~DynamicCharArray()
{
}
```

in main.cpp:

.
.
.

```
DynamicCharArray myDynamicCharArray1 = DynamicCharArray();

myDynamicCharArray1.insert(0,'a');
```

.
.
.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Your class already violates the rule of 3 (no copy constructor, no assignment operator).  Why not start off with a general linked list implementation, maybe even a templated one.  Then it doesn't matter if it's char, double, int, etc.

Comment: Yes, that does make more sense to me. Never even thought of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simply answer your question, it happens because of a syntax error while you're calling the function InterInsert:

```
void DynamicCharArray::insert(int index,char input)   //insert an element into array
{
InterInsert(node *&head, node *&last, int index, char input);
}
```

In this case you have a prototype definition inside a function, which is illegal. To actually perform a **function call**, do this instead:

```
void DynamicCharArray::insert(int index, char input)   //insert an element into array
{
    node* head = new node; // you should probably edit these...
    node* last = new node;
    InterInsert(head, last, index, input);
}
```